# Conexant modem in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, modem

Previously linuxant release driver for conexant modem (HCF or HSF), now for newer kernel this site doesn't release for newer kernel version (after 2.6.31-17 version). how to use conexant modem in Ubuntu with newer Kernel than 2.6.31-17 (... , 10.4 , ...)?

Linuxant Ubuntu driver : 
http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/full/downloads-ubuntu-x86.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a compile-it-yourself option. See [here](http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/full/downloads.php#generic).

Download the `tar` and then follow `METHOD C` on the [installation instructions](http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/install.php).

Following your comment, I decided to try building it. It went fine. Here's what I did:

- Download and extract the tar for the right arch.
- `cd` into the new directory and then

  ```
  sudo make debprecomp
  ```
- Assuming everything worked, there should be a `.deb` file sitting in the directory above the current working dir. Just double-click it and it should install.

After that just follow the rest of the installation instructions.

Comment: Are you sure that this way work on newer version of kernel like 2.6.31 ?

Comment: No but you can easily find out.

Comment: Well I just built it fine. I don't have an applicable modem so I can't test if it works. I'm using the mainline 2.6.35 so I assume it should build for things in between .31 and .35 too.

Answer (score 1):

Also Dell provide this driver.
I have used it long time ago.

Try [this page](http://support.us.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R192374&formatcnt=0&libid=0&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=264259) or looking for similar items on dell support.

Comment: I need this driver for newer version of kernel